# Get Hierarchial Data using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
ID  Name    Designation PID
1   E1  D1            0
2   E2  D2            0
3   E3  D3            1
4   E4  D3            1
5   E5  D4            3
6   E6  D4            3
7   E7  D4            2
8   E8  D4            2
```

How can we get all the child employees based on the parent employee using LINQ ?

For eg., if we want child records for employee E1 we should get E3,E4,E5,E6

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using one single LINQ query. But you can do it using a recursive function smth like:

```
IList<Employee> GetAllChildren(IList<Employee> employees, int pid)
{
    var children = employees.Where (e => e.PID == pid).ToList();
    children.AddRange (children.SelectMany (e => GetAllChildren (employees, e.ID)).ToList());

    return children;
}
```